# How to convert a date which is in user timezone to JST or any other timezone using Date() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to convert a date which i get from new Date() to JST timezone or any other timezone without using any JavaScript library. The method should be generalized so that in future if i want to switch to any other timezone, it should be able to do so.

Comment: What is your question? What did you do so far?

Answer (score 0):

Timezones are not that straight forward (some locations do not follow the rules), so you will never get that accurate without a lib which includes a DB of locations e.g., https://github.com/mde/timezone-js

However, I believe you're looking for `getTimezoneOffset()`